# Найти количество повторений поля в колонке типа json в PostgreSQL базе

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста, есть таблица item, в таблице есть колонка source с типом JSON, в ней хранятся следующие данные в таком формате

```js
{
   "id":"1111111",
   "type":"type3333",
   "entities":[
      {
         "nextid":"33333",
         "priceBreaks":[
            {
               "price":111111,
               "customer":1
            }
         ],
         "amount":0.0
      },
      {
         "nextid":"55555",
         "priceBreaks":[
            {
               "price":33333,
               "customer":2
            }
         ],
         "amount":0.0
      },
```

и так далее

но также бывает и вот такой вид jsona когда на один nextid несколько priceBreak

```js
{
   "id":"1111111",
   "type":"type3333",
   "entities":[
      {
         "nextid":"33333",
         "priceBreaks":[
            {
               "price":111111,
               "customer":1
            }
         ],
         "amount":0.0
      },
      {
         "nextid":"55555",
         "priceBreaks":[
            {
               "price":33333,
               "customer":2
            }
         ],
             "priceBreaks":[
            {
               "price":88888,
               "customer":3
            }
         ]
         "amount":0.0
      },
```

и так далее

Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить количество повторений поля priceBreak во всей таблице item в первом примере и во втором?

Comment: Если тип поля действительно json, то второй случай просто невозможен, в json ключи всегда уникальны.